# Use PagedList with Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-paging

I am implementing a Google Maps view that shows some points pinned in the viewport that the user map camera is. When the user moves the camera by dragging the map, the application must fetch new points in the new viewport and display it.

I was wondering if it's possible to implement this using `PagedList`, `AsyncPagedListDiffer` and a `BoundaryCallback` in an analogous way to what `RecyclerView.PagedListAdapter` does when it reaches the end of a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: You may want to keep an eye on my question which is similar here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794465/how-to-use-paging-library-with-room-dao-without-using-any-view-classes